# How to compensate for MySQL timezone difference?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timezone

I store times in MySQL sent from a PHP script as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. This makes times from the wrong timezone, minus 1 hour from where I am. I'm not superuser, so `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/London';` won't work. Is there anyway I can modify the input or output query to compensate 1 hour?

This is my current sql query, sent from a form:

```
REPLACE INTO `order_admin_message` (`order_id`, `message`, `date_updated`)
VALUES ('$number', '$msg', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

And then I retreive it using:

```
SELECT order_admin_message.message, order_admin_message.date_updated
FROM order_admin_message
WHERE order_admin_message.order_id = $number
```

EDIT: To be clear, I don't want to show the user's time, just local London time (taking daylight saving into account in summer).
EDIT 2: Changed the subject to be closer to the question/answer.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to change it globally? Can't you just change it for the current session?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm a newbie. Maybe I don't need to change it globally? All I'm after is the make the time display correctly.

Comment: `REPLACE INTO order_admin_message WHERE $number IS SQL INJECTION`.

Comment: @tadman Nah, it's ok. This is in the admin section, behind closed doors.

Comment: You develop bad habits like that and one day you'll get burned. "It's only an admin thing" sounds like famous last words. One day "Jimmy O'Neil" will get hired and your system will explode.

Comment: @tadman "I think have a backup of the database" will be my famous last words... :)

Comment: If you just want the time to display correctly just display UTC time and put a note "All times are in UTC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, just change it for your display. Don't store locale dependent dates or times in a database. Makes conversion later on, a PITA. Just display the time/timezone you need even if you *don't care about the user*.

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

$datetime_updated = new DateTime($results['order_admin_message.date_updated']);
$datetime_updated->setTimezone($tz);
$display_date = $datetime_updated->format("M j, Y g:i A");

echo $display_date;
```

Comment: this works but Europe/London time is the same as UTC, i.e. one hour off. Setting it to Paris gives the correct London time, which it obviously shouldn't. Could something be misconfigured here?

Comment: Not sure without seeing more information. What timezone is your server in? Is it's time configured correctly?

Comment: Server is in UTC, but I had screwed up the timezone setting earlier in the PHP script. Working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `utc_timestamp` instead, and convert to the timezone of the user yourself.

UTC_TIMESTAMP is the current UTC date and time, as recognised all over the world.

As long as you know where your user is and what his timezone is, you can convert it by adding the correct offset.

If you don't know what the user's desired timezone is, then you have a different problem - basically you need to find out somehow.

Comment: Can you be more specific? UTC_TIMESTAMP generates the same time as CURRENT. I found an ugly solution like NOW + INTERVAL 1 HOUR but that will probably mess things up in daylight saving time.

Comment: UTC_TIMESTAMP is the current UTC date and time, as recognised all over the world. As long as you know where your user is and what his timezone is, you can convert it by adding the correct offset. If you don't know what the user's desired timezone is, then you have a different problem - basically you need to find out somehow...

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify - I want to use London time only. Don't care about the user's time.

Comment: Then all you need is a table with time intervals for when London daylight savings starts and ends each year, and you can convert using a UDF `UTCTOLONDON()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONVERT_TZ()` function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz